# How do I display my 'Artist' categories in a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm currently customising the theme 'Sidecar' for a Bigcartel site, and im trying to add a dropdown menu that populates with only the Artist links on the fixed sidebar.

I've tried using just the simple  code to surround the  but this doesnn't seem to work. It wont drop down, or show anything at all, other than what is pictured below.

Can anyone help ?

Before I added the dropdown - https://db.tt/gYoAFdW3

Then after I applied the code below - https://db.tt/w3UFxzoA

```
{% if artists.active != blank %}
    <section>
        <h2 class="title">Artists</h2>
        <select>  
            <ul>
                {% for artist in artists.active %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ artist.url }}" class="page {% if page.full_url contains artist.url %}current{% endif %}">
                            {{ artist.name }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </select>
    </section>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use caps as sparingly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  {% if artists.active != blank %}
    <section>
      <h2 class="title">Artists</h2>
       <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">  
         {% for artist in artists.active %}
        <option value="{{ artist.url }}">{{ artist.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </section>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Cheers dude, appreciate it !